# Haskell Couldn't Match Expected Types

Tags: haskell

So, I've been banging my head against the wall for at least an hour now.  Here's my problem:

One of my functions returns `[(Text, Text)]`.

Now I want to populate Document in `Data.Bson` using this list of tuples.

With the extension `OverloadedStrings` turned on, and with `Data.Text` imported as well as `Data.Bson`, I do (this part is edited from original post, which I pasted a debug version of the code which actually doesn't use the accumulator):

```
tuplesToBSON :: [(Text, Text)] -> Document
tuplesToBSON xs = L.foldr (\v acc -> merge [fst v =: snd v] acc) [] xs
```

Where `merge` is from the Data.Bson package, as is `=:`.

No luck.  It complains: Couldn't match expected type `Label` with actual type `Text`.  (below is also an edit for clarity) If I try:

```
tuplesToBSON xs = L.foldr (\v acc -> merge [(fst v) =: (String (snd v))] acc ) [] xs
```

where this unfortunately named `String` is actually a constructor (I think...) from the Bson package for a data type called "Value".  http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bson/0.2.1/doc/html/src/Data-Bson.html

This still doesn't work--but a different error message:

```
No instance for (Val Value) arising from a use of `=:'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Val Value)
In the expression: (fst v) =: (String (snd v))
In the first argument of `merge', namely `[(fst v) =: (String (snd v))]'
In the expression: merge [(fst v) =: (String (snd v))] acc
```

as well as:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Label' with actual type `Text'
Expected type: [(Label, text-0.11.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text)] Actual type: [(Text, Text)]
In the third argument of `L.foldr', namely `xs'
In the expression: L.foldr (\ v acc -> merge [(fst v) =: (String (snd v))] acc) [] xs
```

I know that Value is a data type from the Bson package, but I really don't know what `Val` is.

===== START of now IRRELEVANT PORTION =====

And as one of the answers below pointed out, in the original post, I had `:: String` in my code "casting" a `Text` to a `String` as in the Prelude.  I actually thought `:: String` was referring to the one mentioned in the Bson package, but I was completely wrong anyway, because (I think) `String` is actually a constructor.

I suspect somehow the GHC type inference is confused somehow, because the following works fine:

```
testDocument :: Document
testDocument = [(fst ("asdf", "awef") :: Label) =: ("asdf" :: String)]
```

Edit: This works but must be because Bson does some proper type handling automatically because after included the line `import Prelude hiding (String)` it gives me an error as it should.

So I've finally cleaned up the question.  Sorry for the previous messy version--I was quite frustrated.

Comment: Incidentally, you're dropping the `acc` on the floor. Maybe you meant to use `((fst v) := (snd v)) : acc` instead of just returning a 1-element list?

Comment: oh yeah, that was actually still debug code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem isn't the `Label`, it's the `b0`. Looks like you're trying to assert that `snd v` is a `String` when it's not. Try using something like

```
tuplesToBSON xs = L.foldr (\acc v ->  [ ((fst v) :: Label) := (unpack (snd v) :: String)] ) [] xs
```

Although I'm not quite sure what all the inline type assertions are for. This is probably more readable as

```
tuplesToBSON xs = L.foldr (\acc v -> [(fst v) := (unpack (snd v0)]) [] xs
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  let me edit my post because i forgot i should have included a more proper line of code involving the foldr.  EDIT: actually forget about the editing of original, i have a better idea of what's the issue now, i'll just append an edit.

Comment: thanks for comment on String part--I wasn't quite thinking the Prelude.String, but I definitely confused the String constructor for Bson's Value data.  Closer now; still having trouble!

Comment: @Victor: Your updated code uses `=:`, but the `Data.Bson` operator appears to be `:=`.

Comment: oh i see.  But I don't understand the := definition--what's the "!" in "!Label"?

Comment: @Victor: It introduces strictness into the data definition. Basically, it prevents that field from being boxed.

Comment: ok.  so i'm using := now, seems like more control.  down to just 1 message now!      =========Couldn't match expected type Label' with actual type Text'
    `Expected type: [(Label, text-0.11.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text)]`
        `Actual type: [(Text, Text)]`=======
Any ideas?  I thought Label is just a synonym for Text.

Comment: if i just change the type signature to [(Label, Text)], it still complains:     ======`Expected type: [(Label, text-0.11.2.0:Data.Text.Internal.Text)]`
      `Actual type: [(Label, Text)]`======

Comment: @Victor: I don't suppose your Data.Text library is a different version than the one that your Data.Bson links to? I'm not experienced with version conflicts in Haskell so I don't know what sort of error that would be expected to emit, but your error message is very curious.

Comment: Turns out it is dependency hell!  Or something... something there was a text-0.11.2.2 snuck in there somewhere.  ghc-pkg unregister that package and now it compiled just fine!  I posted that specific question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/11957974/haskell-how-to-solve-possible-version-conflict and edited the question to "solved".

Answer (score 0):

First off, it isn't clear what you are trying to do.  You aren't even using the accumulator (`acc`) so this is a degenerate traversal.  You might as well say:

```
tuplesToBSON = (\v -> fst v =: snd v) . last
```

Another issue is your types are clearly contradictory.  You say you're passing in a `Text` then inside the lambda you explicitly state you think the variable should be a `String`.  You can't just add type annotations and think of them as a coerce operation, as you say in the question.  The type of a variable must remain consistent and any coercion is done by an explicit function application (`unpack` in this case).

So lets assume that's just a mistaken use of foldr and we want to actually use the accumulator.  Lets further assume you want the `Text` type and any use of `String` was just accidental.

The third issue is it seems you have your variables mixed up, in a `foldr` the second argument is the accumulator, not the first.  So we should have:

```
tuplesToBSON = foldr (\v acc -> (fst v =: snd v) : acc) []
```

And this type checks fine.  If the eta reduction and other clean-ups make it too hard for you to see the similarity to your code then consider this version:

```
tuplesToBSON xs = foldr (\v acc -> ((fst v :: Label) =: (snd v :: Text)) : acc ) [] xs
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually pasted in the debug code and what I meant to paste in was something that actually uses the accumulator... let me try your suggestions first though.  thanks for the reply.

Comment: And thanks for the comment on foldr (\v acc) order of variables.  It would have taken me ages to figure that one out.